# Sitecore: How to check if ImageMagick is used or not?

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagemagick, sitecore

Mine is a .NET and Sitecore based application. How do I check for my application if it's using ImageMagick or any related plugin or not?

Answer (score 1):

1. Normally, a .NET library (such as [Magick.NET](https://magick.codeplex.com/)) would be used. Look through every project's references to see if any of them says "Magick" or "ImageMagick".
2. In some projects, ImageMagick may be invoked directly, since it's a command-line tool. To find if that's the case, just use full-text search in your solution. Go to menu *Edit –> Find and Replace –> Find in Files*, select *"Entire Solution"* in the *"Look in"* drop-down list, and search for "magick".
3. To see whether there are any ImageMagick binaries in the solution, open your solution's folder in Windows Explorer, press Ctrl+F and search for "magick" and "imagemagick".